# HttpWebRequest using GET on redirect instead of POST like idHttp

Tags: c#, delphi, httpwebrequest

Sorry for my english.

In Delphi I have an idHttp component with the hoWaitForUnexpectedData option activated.

When I send a POST request to a URL, it redirects the client to a second URL with the same POST request and headers. Also, the server response contains "Connection: keep-alive" in its header.

However, when I try to do the same request in C# with a HttpWebRequest component, it redirects to the second URL using the method GET.

I need the C# HttpWebRequest component to work like the Delphi idHTTP one does. I don't understand why it uses a GET instead of a POST when following the redirection.

Here's my code in Delphi, using hoWaitForUnexpectedData:

```
  // The server is supposed to send a 'Content-Length' header without sending
  // the actual data. 1xx, 204, and 304 replies are not supposed to contain
  // entity bodies, either...
  if TextIsSame(ARequest.Method, Id_HTTPMethodHead) or
     TextIsSame(ARequest.MethodOverride, Id_HTTPMethodHead) or
     ((AResponse.ResponseCode div 100) = 1) or
     (AResponse.ResponseCode = 204) or
     (AResponse.ResponseCode = 304) then
  begin
    // Have noticed one case where a non-conforming server did send an
    // entity body in response to a HEAD request.  If requested, ignore
    // anything the server may send by accident
    if not (hoWaitForUnexpectedData in FOptions) then begin
      Exit;
    end;
    Result := CheckForPendingData(100);
  end
  else if (AResponse.ResponseCode div 100) = 3 then
  begin
    // This is a workaround for buggy HTTP 1.1 servers which
    // does not return any body with 302 response code
    Result := CheckForPendingData(5000);
  end else begin
    Result := True;
  end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An HTTP redirect, by definition from the standard, should be handled using a GET. Therefore, if you send a POST and get a redirect as an answer, the expected behavior is to perform a GET to the redirect address. I suspect the old Delphi component is following old practices and replicates the call including with the POST verb.

I would try to disable [AllowAutoRedirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect(v=vs.110).aspx) in the HttpWebRequest object and handle this manually, as your case seems to differ from the standard.

Comment: There are several HTTP response codes related to redirects. The problem is related to the `302` redirect in particular. Different HTTP clients handle `302` differently, because its behavior is not spelled out very well in the HTTP spec.  `303` was created to help address that ambiguity, but not all servers use it yet (or use it correctly),and not all clients recognize it yet.

Answer (score 1):

The `hoWaitForUnexpectedData` option has no effect on how `TIdHTTP` handles redirects, and neither does the section of code you quoted.

However, the `hoTreat302Like303` option does affect redirect handling.  If `TIdHTTP` receives a `303` redirect, or receives a `302` redirect with `hoTreat302Like303` enabled, `TIdHTTP` sends the new request as a `GET`.  Otherwise, it sends the new request using the same verb as the redirected request.  This is by design, and there is a series of comments in the implementation code of the `TIdHTTPProtocol.ProcessResponse()` method explaining the rational behind this behavior:

```
  // GDG 21/11/2003. If it's a 303, we should do a get this time

  // RLebeau 7/15/2004 - do a GET on 302 as well, as mentioned in RFC 2616

  // RLebeau 1/11/2008 - turns out both situations are WRONG! RFCs 2068 and
  // 2616 specifically state that changing the method to GET in response
  // to 302 and 303 is errorneous.  Indy 9 did it right by reusing the
  // original method and source again and only changing the URL, so lets
  // revert back to that same behavior!

  // RLebeau 12/28/2012 - one more time. RFCs 2068 and 2616 actually say that
  // changing the method in response to 302 is erroneous, but changing the
  // method to GET in response to 303 is intentional and why 303 was introduced
  // in the first place. Erroneous clients treat 302 as 303, though.  Now
  // encountering servers that actually expect this 303 behavior, so we have
  // to enable it again! Adding an optional HTTPOption flag so clients can
  // enable the erroneous 302 behavior if they really need it.
```

The jist of it is that the HTTP spec says to send a `GET` for a `303` redirect, whereas it is ambiguous about whether to send a `GET` for `302`. Some browsers do, some do not. That is why the `hoTreat302Like303` option was added, though it is disabled by default for backwards compatibility with earlier Indy versions.

So, the behavior you describe means you must be encountering a `302` redirect, with `hoTreat302Like303` disabled (which it is default).  If you enable that option, `TIdHTTP` will behave more like `HttpWebRequest`, not the other way around.